# How to get the index of the backslash (\) in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this :

```
var name="C:\Users\Desktop\task.txt";
```

I want to get the last index of backslash in the above string.
 
How to do it ?

Comment: See [String.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 9):

There are no backslashes in that string.

The backslashes in the *source code* of the string literal will be treated as escape characters and consumed by the time the string is constructed.

`\U` becomes U, `\D` becomes D, and `\t` becomes a tab.

```js
var name="C:\Users\Desktop\task.txt";
console.log(name);
```

If there were any backslashes in the string, then you could use `lastIndexOf` (keeping in mind that you would need to escape the backslash in the needle as well as the haystack).

```js
var name = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\task.txt";
console.log(name);
console.log(name.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Comment: I want to get the index value of \ just before task. so that i can strip task.txt from the string . How to do it ?

Comment: @sahithi — I refer you back to the first sentence of this answer. There is no ```\``` before *task*. There is a **tab** before *ask*. (Therefore: You can't).

Answer (score 0):

I got the filename alone by

```
var filename=document.getElementById('file').value;
     var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        originalfilename = filename.substring(lastIndex +1);
    }
```